# Cocos2d 2.0 draw method errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I use cocos2d 2.0. I get an error: `property 'world' not found on object of type 'ColoredCircleSprite *'` **What I wrote wrong in the draw method?**

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    self.world->DrawDebugData();
    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

I tried to do as there shown: [Cocos2D 2.0 OpenGL errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914914/cocos2d-2-0-opengl-errors)

Also I saw another way to do draw method, I must delete `self.` from `self.world->DrawDebugData();` line and if I do that I get another error: `Use undeclared identifier 'world'`.

That is `ColoredCircleSprite.h` code:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface ColoredCircleSprite : CCNode <CCRGBAProtocol, CCBlendProtocol> {
    float       radius_;
    GLubyte     opacity_;
    ccColor3B   color_;

    NSUInteger numberOfSegments;
    GLfloat *circleVertices_;

    ccBlendFunc blendFunc_;
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) float radius;

/** Opacity: conforms to CCRGBAProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) GLubyte opacity;
/** Opacity: conforms to CCRGBAProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) ccColor3B color;
/** BlendFunction. Conforms to CCBlendProtocol protocol */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) ccBlendFunc blendFunc;

/** creates a Circle with color and radius */
+ (id) circleWithColor: (ccColor4B)color radius:(GLfloat)r;

/** initializes a Circle with color and radius */
- (id) initWithColor:(ccColor4B)color radius:(GLfloat)r;

- (BOOL) containsPoint:(CGPoint)point;

@end
```

I just copy and paste code from cocos2d-iphone.com forum. **I don't really know what variable should be there and should whether there be any variable.**

Thanks.

Comment: What is self in code? In which class you have thi draw method?

Comment: ColoredCircleSprite.m Hmmm, I just trying to Run my app and I get and an error.

Comment: Do you have world as an iVar inside that class?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ColoredCircleSprite : CCSprite
{
    b2World         *mWorld;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) b2World         *world;
@end


@implementation ColoredCircleSprite
@synthesize world = mWorld;

-(void)initBox2D
{    
    //create world in right place...
    self.world = new b2World(gravity);
}
@end
```

Comment: initBox2D method? For what? That is my interface:`@interface ColoredCircleSprite : CCNode <CCRGBAProtocol, CCBlendProtocol>`. Now in cocos2d we should use initBox2D instead draw? I didn't see that in Documentation. I'm new in cocos2d can you explain me why I have to use initBox2D method? Thx

Comment: @user1454115, no no, I just written that to show initialization. search new b2World in ur code and assign that to ur world pointer in coloredCircleSprite. I used initBox2D method. its my own method and called from game init :)

Comment: What is `new b2World`? Look at my question, I edited it. There is mine ColoredCircleSprite.h code which from them is "world pointer"? As I see there are lot of pointers :)

Comment: @user1454115, that draw function is used to show only box2D shapes for debug purpose..in ur class, i think u not using box2D..so safely u can remove entire draw function.