# how to turn off opengl logging in xcode?

Tags: xcode, opengl, cocos2d-iphone

or explain me what this means, because everything works perfectly.

```
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 280
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 280
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 280
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 280
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 280
```

I use storyboards and cocos2d. cocos2d is used only for sprite generation

Comment: Probably it is the same problem then here: [Cocos2D 2.0 - Zillions of OpenGL errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662770/cocos2d-2-0-zillions-of-opengl-errors) the answer at least is about the `0x506` error

Comment: I read this answer. But I don't have draw function. I just initialize cocos2d and then these errors appears

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914914/cocos2d-2-0-opengl-errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started to get such errors when migrated to autolayout in iOS 6.0. The problem was because of incorrect frame size for CCGLView:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:container.frame pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 depthFormat:0 preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:nil multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0];
```

When I output container.frame into console, I get {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}. What's strange because in the storyboard container view has a correct size. It works fine when I manually set frame:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 37, 195, 253) pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 depthFormat:0 preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:nil multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0];
```

It's a quick fix and a starting point to dig deeper

Comment: find any solutions to this? i'm currently having the same problem